# Название процесса базы данных ms sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Возможно, я не очень понимаю, как работают базы данных, и у меня возник вопрос. Если у базы данных есть сервер, то нужно ли его запускать и есть ли у него вообще процесс? У меня есть скрипт, который подключается к базе данных ms sql на локальном компьютере и он работает и нормально подключается, однако, в диспетчере задач я не смог найти процесс сервера базы данных. Есть ли он вообще или я что-то не так понимаю?
P.S. В интернете ответ на свой вопрос не нашел, видимо, он мало кого волнует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос не в том, понимаете ли Вы как работает БД или нет, вопрос в том - зачем это Вам? Если ради спортивного интереса, то сам процесс называется **sqlservr.exe** (возможны вариации, в зависимости от используемой версии). Останавливается и запускается же бд через менеджеры(**SSMS**, как вариант), либо напрямую через сервисы системы остановкой/пуском соответствующего сервиса. "Прибивать" процесс  через диспетчер задач крайне не советую - БД после такой аварийной остановки может не подняться.